# Animation only happening on one checkbox despite different classes

Tags: html, css, svg

I have found a checkbox which I really want to use but when I add more than 1 checkbox the animation only applies to the first one.

I have tried creating new class's like `.cbx2` and `.inp-cbx2` and applying the same style's but the animation still only applies to the first checkbox.

Could you please explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

```css
/* #### CHECKBOX STYLES AND ANIMATION #### */
.cbx {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cbx span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.cbx span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2bbfcb;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.cbx span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.cbx:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
}

.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child {
  background: #2bbfcb;
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(3.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}



/* #### CHECKBOX STYLES AND ANIMATION #### */
.cbx2 {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cbx2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx2 span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.cbx2 span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx2 span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2bbfcb;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.cbx2 span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.cbx2:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
}

.inp-cbx2:checked + .cbx2 span:first-child {
  background: #2bbfcb;
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}
.inp-cbx2:checked + .cbx2 span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.inp-cbx2:checked + .cbx2 span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(3.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
          <input class="inp-cbx" id="cbx" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
          <label class="cbx" for="cbx"><span>
          <svg width="40px" height="40px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg></span><span>DIRECT</span></label>


          <input class="inp-cbx2" id="cbx2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
          <label class="cbx2" for="cbx"><span>
          <svg width="40px" height="40px" viewbox="0 0 12 10" class="c">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg></span><span>MUTI ROUTE</span></label>
```

Comment: You forgot to change `for="cbx"` to `cbx2` for the second `<label>`, so it's triggering the first checkbox… No need for multiple classes.

Comment: perhaps it is cbx > span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole reason classes exist in CSS is to make your styles reusable across multiple elements. There is no need to duplicate your CSS.

The reason the second check box doesn't work when using the same classes as the first is because you haven't updated the second labels `for` property. This property tells the browser the `id` of the form element that should be effected when the label is clicked.

In your case, the second label should look like this:

```
<label class="cbx" for="cbx2"><span>
```

```css
/* #### CHECKBOX STYLES AND ANIMATION #### */

.cbx {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cbx span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cbx span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.cbx span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cbx span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2bbfcb;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.cbx span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.cbx:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
}

.inp-cbx:checked+.cbx span:first-child {
  background: #2bbfcb;
  border-color: #2bbfcb;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}

.inp-cbx:checked+.cbx span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.inp-cbx:checked+.cbx span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(3.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="inp-cbx" id="cbx" type="checkbox" style="display: none;" />
<label class="cbx" for="cbx"><span>
<svg width="40px" height="40px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
    <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
</svg></span><span>DIRECT</span></label>


<input class="inp-cbx" id="cbx2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;" />
<label class="cbx" for="cbx2"><span>
<svg width="40px" height="40px" viewbox="0 0 12 10" class="c">
    <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
</svg></span><span>MUTI ROUTE</span></label>
```

Comment: I see now. I'm not used to dealing with the `for` property and for some reason, it didn't come into my mind that it might be the thing causing the problem. Thank you!